# Safe to git rebase new local branch using various remote commits?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

Assume I have a local repo which is completely up-to-date with origin.

Is it safe to create a new branch from a specific SHA and then do all the rebasing I want of my new branch against other branches/SHAs which exist on origin?

```
git checkout -b merging_some_commits bfd70a83f5bf3f7fd44422233a82751535428cbd

git rebase --onto some_other_branch 02979b4e34809d53e5071501046f59ad5c

git checkout some_other_branch

git merge mergin_some_commits

git push origin some_other_branch
```

Update: I'm basically trying to cherry pick `02979b...` - `bfd70a83...` into `some_other_branch`. `02979b...` is an ancestor of `bfd70a83...` Neither share a recent history with `some_other_branch`.  Assume there are 10-15 commits before `02979b...` to shared common ancestor which I  do not want (yet). Eventually these 10-15 commits will need to be merged as well.

Comment: It would help to know what the two SHA's refer to... is 02979b4e34809d53e5071501046f59ad5c an ancestor of bfd70a83f5bf3f7fd44422233a82751535428cbd ?  and are either ancestors of some_other_branch?

Comment: Updated... I'm assuming that if you even had to ask, then I don't want to be doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you have there looks fine, and it should do what you are describing you want in your update.  As @haydenmuhi described, pretty much anything is "safe" in your local repository.  When you push, all that matters is the commits that are on the branch you are pushing--where they came from and any other branches you have won't make a difference.

As far as later merging the other 10-15 commits, you should be able to do that in the future just fine either simply merging `02979b` or `bfd70a83`, or by rebasing `some_other_branch..02979b` or `some_other_branch..02979b`.  If it's still going to be a while before you merge those, you still may want to rebase them onto `some_other_branch` now to help keep them a bit mroe current.

Comment: Thanks, I can not take everything before `029` yet because it would screw up other peoples refactoring. I would have just used `merge` if I could though.

Answer (score 4):

If a commit is local, and only local, you can do whatever you want with it. So long as you have never pushed that commit to a remote repo, it is fair game to modify in any way, including rebasing. It doesn't matter what you rebase on top of, because child commits do not affect their ancestors.

Comment: I performed the rebase and no new commits were created. In fact existing commits now appear twice when viewing history in smartgit (only used for viewing and diff'ing history). A new commit will be created by the merge into `merge_come_commits`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I would have marked your's as answer, but it was still partially over my head.